# Nested workflow - The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I use the [local docker StepFunctions setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-docker.html) and try to invoke StateMachine within a StateMachine (nested workflow), using `sync` or `waitForTaskToken`. But have this error (see below).

Does anyone know what this means? Is it because local StepFunctions service don't allow StateMachine calling another StateMachine?

```json
2021-01-15 02:11:03.336: arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:execution:Foobar-Dev:6bae52c1-3562-44a5-88fd-68a533f054bf : 
{
    "Type":"TaskFailed",
    "PreviousEventId":29,
    "TaskFailedEventDetails":{
        "ResourceType":"states",
        "Resource":"startExecution.sync",
        "Error":"StepFunctions-AWSStepFunctionsException",
        "Cause":"The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: ca3a983d-3496-4d48-854a-1bb803a44f2a; Proxy: null)"
    }
}
```

Main workflow definition:

```json
    "FoobarWorkflow": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:stateMachine:Foobar-Dev",
        "Input": {
          "NeedCallback": false,
          "AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
        }
      },
```

Child workflow definition:

```json
{
    "Comment": "Foobar-Dev",
    "StartAt": "Screening",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "TimeoutSeconds": 480,
    "States": {
        "Screening": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:activity:ScreeningActivity-Dev",
            "Next": "ScreeningChoiceState",
            "Retry": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "States.TaskFailed",
                  "States.Runtime"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 3,
                "MaxAttempts": 3,
                "BackoffRate": 2
              }
            ],
            "Catch": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "States.TaskFailed",
                  "States.Runtime"
                ],
                "Next": "DefaultSystemFailure",
                "ResultPath": "$.error"
              },
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "States.ALL"
                ],
                "Next": "DefaultSystemFailure",
                "ResultPath": "$.error"
              }
            ]
        },
        ...
 "ScreeningFinalDecision": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:activity:ScreeningFinalDecision-Dev",
            "End": true
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, it seems like for local StepFunction docker setup, we need to pass additional environment variables for `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` to enable the nested workflow to work.

The doc talks about this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-config-options.html#docker-credentials).

> To configure Step Functions Local for Docker, create the following
> file: `aws-stepfunctions-local-credentials.txt`.
>
> This file contains your credentials and other configuration options,
> such as the following.
>
> ```
> AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=AWS_REGION_OF_YOUR_AWS_RESOURCES
> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY
> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY
> ```
>
> Once you have configured your credentials and configuration options in
> aws-stepfunctions-local-credentials.txt, start Step Functions with the
> following command.
>
> ```
> docker run -p 8083:8083 --env-file aws-stepfunctions-local-credentials.txt amazon/aws-stepfunctions-local
> ```

Comment: Confusing because it doesn't require them to be valid access_keys or key_ids.  Just having any values appears to overcome the error.